# How to implement help in Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) application?

Tags: java, kepler, help-system

I have an E4 RCP application and I need to add a Help system to it. 
As I have understood from a post in the same forum, called **Eclipse e4 and org.eclipse.help.ui**, it "*seems that pure Eclipse 4 code currently (as in Eclipse juno 4.2) lacks support for help...*". Is this problem solved in Kepler? I have added org.eclipse.help.ui and org.eclipse.help.webapp but I have no idea of how can I implement a handler to open the help content.

Comment: Start by creating hlp files.

Comment: ok, but how to bind them to the application in a nice way?